# Is there any way to auto upgrade Ansible roles?

Tags: ansible, upgrade

Is there any way to upgrade Ansible version along with the playbooks which are written in older version of Ansible. Any kind of script which would read all the modules in the playbooks and recommend / update them to new versions

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing that would do this automatically.